# How to use a PHP function for multiple calls within the same PHP page?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to use a php function to get the prices of a tola (11.664 grams) at an order status page.  The function uses a php page 'priceApi4CurCtrl.php' that fetches the price data from a website using an external API.  My function is as follows:

```
function tolaPrice($cur_pick) {
    require('priceApi4CurCtrl.php');

    if($cur_pick == 'pkr') {
        $tola_price = $bitprice_pkr*10*11.664;
        return $tola_price;    
    } elseif($cur_pick == 'usd') {
        $tola_price = $bitprice_usd*10*11.64;
        return $tola_price;
    } elseif($cur_pick == 'aed') {
        $tola_price = $bitprice_aed*10*11.64;
        return $tola_price;
    }
}
// Succeeds for the first call as under
$cur_pick = 'pkr';
echo tolaPrice($cur_pick);
// Fails for the second call as under
$cur_pick = 'aed';
echo tolaPrice($cur_pick);
```

The function works fine for the first call using `echo tolaPrice($cur_pick)`. However, it fails all subsequent calls and hence I am unable to complete the order status of second and subsequent orders.

I am not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what doesn't work? And maybe what `priceApi4CurCtrl.php` contains? I cannot reproduce your "fail".

Comment: "subsequent calls", which we cannot see. If you have a problem with some code, you need to show us. We cannot fix things which we know nothing about.

Comment: @ kerbholz @ADyson  I edited the last part of the question. May be this can explain better as to the issue I am facing.

Comment: A demo of the code we can see: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f63eade23b5812f78055d388a3c6f0800113a16e . It works fine (but I had to simulate the values of some variables which were not defined). So...what code is in `priceApi4CurCtrl.php` please? It seems like the issue must be there.

Comment: Also what does "fails" mean, **exactly**? Do you get an error or warning? Or the result is wrong? When describing a problem in your code, please be specific and detailed, because we cannot always guess.

Comment: @ADyson When I say it fails I mean to say it fails to fetch any data.  The first call succeeds to bring the desired price with any and all currencies while second call doesn't fetch any data.  I need to use the fetched prices in a foreach loop in an html table. Probably some feature of PHP that I am not familiar with is preventing the second call from effectively fetching the data.

Comment: well, since the second call is sent with a different parameter value, it would make sense to look at places where the code changes its behaviour / path / output based on that parameter. In what you've shown, the only place is `} elseif($cur_pick == 'aed') {` and I've already demonstrated that (assuming `$bitprice_aed` is defined somewhere), that this part isn't the issue. So again, you need to **show us the code for priceApi4CurCtrl.php**. That seems to be the only place left where a problem could be occurring. Please do that, or else we cannot help you.

Comment: @Adyson you already helped me by giving this clue about file 'priceApi4CurCtrl.php'. I re-did the logic of this file and everything is working fine now. I am now calling the file inside a function file that is then being required in the order status page.  Thanks a lot for the help.  I was able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to wrap an if else loop in a function, I simply calculated the prices in a separate file named tola_price.php as follows:

```
include('priceApi4CurCtrl.php'); 
$tola_price_pkr = $bitprice_pkr*10*11.664;    
$tola_price_usd = $bitprice_usd*10*11.64;
$tola_price_aed = $bitprice_aed*10*11.64;
```

And then called the tola_price.php within my script with if else loop as follows:

```
require_one('tola_price.php');
if($cur_pick == 'pkr') {        
        $tola_price = $tola_price_pkr;    

    } elseif($cur_pick == 'usd') {
       $tola_price = $tola_price_usd;
    } elseif($cur_pick == 'aed') {
       $tola_price = $tola_price_aed;
    }
```

And then used the prices to build further script.
Thanks to those who offered help